# Use .htaccess to prevent root directory from public access

Tags: php, .htaccess

I don't know such thing is possible or not practically, but let's give it a try. In past (more than three years ago), I came to know about solution like this (don't know exactly how it is), in one MVC tutorial.

**Directory structure**

- WebRoot/

  - includes/
  - config/
  - public/

    - images/
    - js/
    - css/
    - index.php
  - init.php

**What I Want To Do Is**

When user access `http://www.mysite.com/a/b/c/`, redirect all requests to `/public/index.php` page. i.e., all requests to website will go through `/public/index.php` page, except `images/`, `js/` and `css/` directories, which are in `public/`.

Also, `http://www.mysite.com/includes/` will redirect to `index.php` page, and get `includes/` as `$query`.

**Index.php page**

```
<?php

// get init file from webroot directory, which will load all required php files.
define ('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once (ROOT . 'init.php');


// get query from url (here, $query = "a/b/c/")
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $query = $_GET['q'];
}

// insert images, css etc. resource
echo "<img src='http://www.mysite.com/images/foo.jpg' />";
echo "<script src='http://www.mysite.com/js/bar.js'></script>";

?>
```

This will be useful for them who are using web-hosting, which doesn't provide one step up directory access to webroot.

**EDIT**

OK, I found the site from where I got this concept. See two .htaccess files used in root directory and public directory. [Link to MVC tutorial](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/)

Comment: @faa yes `/config` and all other content outsite of `public/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the .htaccess is in `WebRoot`.

To rewrite all requests, you just use [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). When you want to exclude some paths, you use one or more [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/index\.php
RewriteRule .* public/index.php?q=$0 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^images/.+ public/$0 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/.+ public/$0 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/.+ public/$0 [L]
```

The flag [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) appends any other existing query string as arguments to `index.php`. If you don't want to append any existing query string, just leave the `QSA` flag out.

If you want the rewrite to be visible to the client, you must add the [`R`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag to the `RewriteRule`, i.e. `[R,L,QSA]` or `[R,L]`.

Comment: Hey you got the plus. Everything is working except images, css and js. To access them simple way is to use `http://www.mysite.com/public/images/foo.jpg`, instead of `http://www.mysite.com/images/foo.jpg`.

Thanks.

Comment: @user1995997 sorry, I missed that. I added rules for these directories.

Comment: one more mistake, in last four lines, `.+ /public/` should be `.+ public/`.

Comment: @user1995997 Ok, fixed that. So, `WebRoot` is not your `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: Yes and no both. On webhosting server WebRoot is DocumentRoot, and on localhost it's not. LOL!!

Comment: @user1995997 I changed `.+` to `.*` in the first `RewriteRule`, because the root directory was still accessible.

Comment: @Olaf Hi, Take a look at link in edited question. It can be done in that way also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another tricks, where your page will not redirected to another page but you will restrict other user to see the directory index

```
Options -Indexes
```

Add this text in your `.htaccess` file, it will generate a 403 errror (forbidden)