# Apache - using .htaccess to throw 403 for root directory only, except of particular IPs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

I've got my *apache server* accessible from Internet through public IP, and domain that points to that IP.

#### What I want to achieve is:

- When user tries to access server's **root dir** `/` using domain or public IP, so `http://example.com/` or `http://178.37.8.6/`, he gets **403 forbidden**
- However, when user uses full URL to any specific file or directory, server **behaves as usual** (so the files are accessible, and directories return typical listing)
  e.g. `http://example.com/casual_directory/`, `http://example.com/awesome_file.html`
- Above rules do not apply **when I access the server from within local network, using local server's ip address** -  `192.168.44.100` or `10.44.0.1`

#### What I've got right now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !=192.168.44.100
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !=10.44.0.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^. - [F,L]
```

While two conditions about ip addresses work properly I think, I'm struggling to make a **correct rule for root directory**.
I've checked, that both `REQUEST_URI` and `REQUEST_FILENAME` returns the same for root directory, namely  "`/`"

***Most likely I cannot compose correct regex there.***

---

I've spent a lot of time doing research, i.a. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470883/use-htaccess-to-prevent-root-directory-from-public-access), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840123/403-forbidden-in-root), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885196/redirect-from-server-root-directory-to-apache-root-directory), [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037594/htaccess-subdirectory-as-root-directory), [here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025312/htaccess-only-allow-access-and-redirect-to-root-index-php-for-only-one-director), [even there](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Transparently_redirect_your_root_directory_to_a_subdirectory#Redirect_.22ONLY.22_the_domain.27s_root_URL_to_a_subdirectory),
[here is a bit different case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470883/use-htaccess-to-prevent-root-directory-from-public-access?lq=1)

But neither of them works as supposed, *one time it's not accessible for any url, the other it doesn't work at all*.

---

*@edit 26.12.2015*

After a few weeks I had to restart my server (which doesn't happen really often) and noticed that **access do root dir `/` was now forbidden** even in my local network (until now it was working as intended).

I had to correct [the solution I mentioned in the comment bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030697/apache-using-htaccess-to-throw-403-for-root-directory-only-except-of-particu#comment55863505_34031217) so now my config is like:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/$">
Require all denied
Require ip 192.168.44.0/24
Require ip 10.44.0.0/24
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use Directory Directives in the Apache vhost config to accomplish what you want.  For apache 2.4

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/path/to/root/$">
    Require all denied
    Require ip 192.168.44.100
    Require ip 10.44.0.1
</DirectoryMatch>

<DirectoryMatch "^/path/to/root/*/">
    Require all granted
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: Actually, my mistake, that's not what I meant, as *accessing from local network*,  it's **when I access the server from within local network, using server's ip** `192.168.44.100` or `10.44.0.1`

Comment: Oh I see. Well I updated the answer with another possible solution.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work as it is, but it was a good idea to try *Directives* instead of .htaccess :)  
I've read on [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) that `Require ip` also applies only to *client* address, so I've changed it to the ip range of network the server will be accessed from: `Require ip 192.168.44.1/192.168.44.254` , `Require ip 10.44.0.1/10.44.0.254`  

Also, I used only the first *DirectoryMatch* directive, (so I assume`"^/path/to/root/$"` refers to the root dir and everything else use default settings).  

After all, it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Ok well I'm glad I was able to help you. If my answer lead you to the answer you can still accept it and/or upvote it.